# Where to put awaitTermination() when using foreachBatch - pyspark streaming

Tags: pyspark, spark-streaming

I have the following code, it executes without any errors, however, it does not populate the meter_reading table in my database, I suspect that the problem might be that I'm missing  .awaitTermination() somewhere. When I try to add this onto the line at the end, as follows:

query = df.writeStream.foreachBatch(process_row).start()\
                      .awaitTermination()

The code bombs out with an error stack stating that foreachBatch only takes one parameter.

My question is, where should awaitTermination() go ?

```
import sys
from pyspark.sql import types, SparkSession, DataFrame, Row
from pyspark.sql.types import *

user= "username"
password  = "****"
database  =  "MeterReportDatabase"
sourceDir = "/user/london_smart_meter/halfhourly_dataset"
datasource_name = "SqlDataPool"

sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.master("local")\
                                   .appName("SparkStreamingAppendMode")\
                                   .getOrCreate()

schema = StructType([StructField('LCLid' , StringType(), True),
                     StructField('tstp'  , TimestampType(), True),
                     StructField('energy', DoubleType(), True)])

hostname = "master-0.master-svc"
port = 1433
db_target_url = "jdbc:sqlserver://%s:%d;database=%s;user=%s;password=%s;" %(hostname, port, database, user, password)
db_target_url

df = sparkSession.readStream\
                 .option("header", "true")\
                 .schema(schema)\
                 .csv("/user/london_smart_meter/halfhourly_dataset")

def process_row(row):
    row.write.jdbc(url=db_target_url, table="meter_reading", mode="append")
    pass
query = df.writeStream.foreachBatch(process_row).start()
```

Comment: You can directly call awaitTermination() method on query instance like 
query = df.writeStream.foreachBatch(process_row).start() 
query.awaitTermination()

Comment: should that be ?:

query = df.writeStream.foreachBatch(process_row).start().awaitTermination()